# Regular expression to create multiple word fragments based off the same words

Tags: javascript, regex, permutation

Let's say I have the following string:

```
var str = "I like barbeque at dawn";
```

I want pairs of all words which are separated by a space. This can be achieved via the following regular expression:

```
  var regex = /[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+/g;
  str.match(regex);
```

This results in:

```
["I like", "barbeque at"]
```

But what if I want ALL permutations of the pairs? The regular expression fails, because it only matches any given word onces. For example, this is what I want:

```
["I like", "like barbeque", "barbeque at", "at dawn"]
```

I know I can use the recursive backtracking pattern to generate permutations. Do regular expressions have the power to create these types of pairs for me?

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead with a capture, which allows overlapping matches:

```
(\w+)\s+(?=(\w+))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tR1tL1/1)

Alternative if you want to capture in one group vs two:

```
(?=(\b\w+\s+\b\w+))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tR1tL1/3)

Comment: You do not need `\b` after `\s` since it is already a non-word character. And `\w` is not `[a-zA-Z]` as in the original post. Why letting digits and underscore? Maybe because other answers inspired you :) ?

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do it:

```
(?=\b([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pN3cK6/3)

**Explanation:**

- We use a look-ahead `(?=...)` in order not to test each position inside the input string. Thus, we'll still "move" through the whole string not consuming any characters
- `\b` will force the regex engine to find the borderline between the matches returned by the subsequent subpattern
- `([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+)` is the capturing group, that will collect 2-word phrases.

Sample code:

```
var re = /(?=\b([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+))/g;
var str = 'i like barbeque at dawn';

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
(\w+)\s+(?=(\w+))
```

and capture the pairs with `($1, $2)`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cE0eH2/1)

```
Input: i like barbeque at dawn

Output: (i, like) (like, barbeque) (barbeque, at) (at, dawn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookaheads for this:

```
var str = "i like barbeque at dawn";
var regex = /(?=\b([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+)\b)/g;
var matches= [];

while ((match = regex.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (match.index === regex.lastIndex)
       regex.lastIndex++;
    matches.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
//=> ["i like", "like barbeque", "barbeque at", "at dawn"]
```